# Xcode 9.2 on macOS 10.14 Mojave

Tags: macos, xcode9.2, macos-mojave

To anyone that has upgrade to macOS 10.14 Mojave, can you install and run Xcode 9.2? Can you build a project with it under that configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: any updates? i need to run older version of xcode i am not able to opne it on mojave

Comment: I don't know. I haven't made the upgrade to Mojave. When I will, if nobody else tested this, I will put here my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm, Xcode 9.2 works well on macOS Mojave. Hope this helps someone.